# how to solve nil error in rspec

Tags: rspec

I have a problem on nil error

My Controller code is:

```
def list
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
end
```

My Rspec code is:

```
it 'should_test_list'
  @user_mock=mock(User)
  User.should_receive(:find).and_return(@user)
  get :list,:id=>1
  assigns[:user].should==''
end
```

I am getting an error that expected ='' got nil

I want to ask that how to solve this error??

I am waiting for reply

Answer (score 3):

The RSpec example declares `@user_mock`, but then the next line uses `@user` instead. Needs to be:

```
User.should_receive(:find).and_return(@user_mock)
```